# Running RDLC reports on Win Server 2012 R2..They die deep in the CLR

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, rdlc, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an winforms application, in VS2013

It runs RDLC reports, and Razor View reports (pulled from our web app)

On my w7 box, both types of reports work...

On server 2012 R2 RDLC reports fail, way down deep in the CLR, and gives the following error:
(But Razor views -> pdf via Rotativa works fine)

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: EFRG3G.exe
  Application Version:  3.1.16.0
  Application Timestamp:    53dc0cb7
  Fault Module Name:    clr.dll
  Fault Module Version: 4.0.30319.34014
  Fault Module Timestamp:   52e0b86c
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000000000003150
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.400.8
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 372e
  Additional Information 2: 372ebc0e88d0905b1dfc62799213ffc9
```

Additional Information 3: 0f90
  Additional Information 4: 0f90fe4c558cb8bf2158eb0f66bc20e2

If I run it in the remote debugger, I get a bit more information:

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in '\\jcdc-d-web-003\d$\WinForm\EFRG3G\EFRG3G.exe'.

Additional information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x95ab3150, on thread 0x42fc. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.
```

It happens right when I try to render the RLDC report like this:

```
LocalReport localViewer =
                new LocalReport
                    {
                        EnableExternalImages = true,
                        ReportEmbeddedResource =
                            "EFRG3G.Reporting.RDLC." + reportRenderParameters.ReportFileName
                    };
         localViewer.DataSources.Add(reportRenderParameters.ReportDataSource);

           // add parameters that rdlc needs
            if (reportRenderParameters.ReportParameters.Count != 0)
                localViewer.SetParameters(reportRenderParameters.ReportParameters);

           // setup subreports
            if (reportRenderParameters.SubReportsDataSources.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (ReportDataSource reportDataSource in reportRenderParameters.SubReportsDataSources)
                {
                    localViewer.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
                }
                localViewer.SubreportProcessing += SetSubReportDataSource;
            }

            Byte[] byteArray = null;

            byteArray = localViewer.Render(  // it blows up right here!!!
                reportRenderParameters.ReportType.ToString( "g" ), "",
                out mimeType,
                out encoding,
                out fileExtension,
                out streamids,
                out warnings );
```

Same code works in vs2008, vs2010

I assumed it was a missing reporting pre req, not installed on the 2102 server so I installed this :

Microsoft.ReportViewer 2012

Which required an install of this:

Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012

but it's still not working...

What else is needed to get vs2013 compiled RDLCs to view on Server 2012 R2?

what else could be causing this error only on Svr 2012 R2, if it's not a missing Prerequisite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, turns out that I didn't need the installers I had above(2012,2008)...

all I needed was the 2010 report viewer distro package. I built the report in vs2010 so that makes sense.

[Get the 2010 Report Viewer Distro package here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownload%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fid%3D6442&ei=Q_7gU97DK4Kq8QHVx4DgAw&usg=AFQjCNFWTsVUNhEj7GQrOr7nR5Jh8lqR8A&sig2=0IfjVBFvqHCRjQIubXdnjA&bvm=bv.72197243,d.b2U)

You can have multiple versions of the distro installed, but I removed the two above, because the viewer was 2012, and the clr types was 2008...

Yes I tried removing the 2008 clr types and installed the 2012 clr types, and that didn't work...

in case someone needs them here are the 2012 clr types (x86 or x64)
You go into the download and you pick which specific packages you want

[Get the 2012 clr types here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownload%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fid%3D29065&ei=C__gU-fcK7Ho8AHzz4GoBA&usg=AFQjCNHSA9mAm3qf3KGM7ithaAh4jSWn5w&sig2=rVaMJ2mLDIIjhHbiRYQ7Rw&bvm=bv.72197243,d.b2U)

and

[Get the 2012 ReportViewer Distro here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownload%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fid%3D35747&ei=av_gU5OQM8mG8QGBqYHIAg&usg=AFQjCNEhvKrZ-tdlxBGVC8xGUMslwTnDqA&sig2=1gNSjtKzk31qAnnQEtrLHw&bvm=bv.72197243,d.b2U)